# Problems to re-setAdapter the listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, parse-platform, android-adapter

I have a problem to update a listview, but doesn't work. Gives the NullPointerException on ".SetAdapter", does anyone know what can be?

Complete code: http://pastebin.com/AZdMi4sc

```
//Get filter from another fragment, using Interface, works fine.
public void setFilter(String tag) {
    getFeedFilter(tag);
}

//Get only itens
private void getFeedFilter(String filter) {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FeedPost");
    query.whereContains("Type", filter);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> responseList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {  
                List<Feed> items = new ArrayList<Feed>();
                for(int i = 0; i < responseList.size(); i++) {
                    items.add(new Feed(responseList.get(i).getString("objectId"),
                            responseList.get(i).getString("Title"));
                }
                adapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), items);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter); // The error occurs here.

            } else {
                System.out.println("error: "+ e);
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Logcat log:

```
 04-27 03:52:23.175    4415-4415/com.fatos.application.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.fatos.application.app.fragment.FeedFragment$6.done(FeedFragment.java:256)
        at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
        at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
        at com.parse.Parse$5$1.run(Parse.java:853)
        .....
```

Comment: Have you checked your `items` is empty or not ?

Comment: can you add the error stack in the logcat

Comment: Probably your listview is null. Have you initialized it prior to setting the adapter? Check it for null. If this doesn't fix the problem, share more if your code, and the logcat output. Also, there's no need to call notifyDatasetChanged if the adapter is not attached to a listview, and if it's already attached, you don't need to reattach, notifyDatasetChanged is enough.

Comment: the listview isn't null, it's only "update".

Comment: Please share your class to be able to get a clear view in what is going on.

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/AZdMi4sc](http://pastebin.com/AZdMi4sc)

Answer (score 0):

1) you should check if the adapter isn't null.this will fix your crash.

```
if(adapter!=null)
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2) you should check if the items returned from response are ok, your problem might be there.

3) your code mixed up, you should init your views and set listeners on one method,
I always call init in fragment - OnCreateView ...

4) The problem might be with your listView, when you are using custom view make sure you give the full location of the custom listview class as your view instead of ListView.

Also, if you just update your adapter, you should not re create your adapter every time. create method in your adapter which set the new data. and just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

For example:

In your adapter code add this:

```
  public void setData(ArrayList<object> newData) {
  this.data = newData;
  }
```

then, in your activity notify adapter :

```
if(items!=null && items.size()>0) {

 if(adapter==null){
 adapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), items);
 }

 else {
 adapter.setData(yourArrayList);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

else {
make toast for us or log to notice items are null...
}

if(adapter!=null)
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I also think you should init your view and set listeners on your onCreateView method, 
because everything is split in your code.

Comment: It didn't work, gave theNullPointerException in adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: as i can see it, something wrong with how your init your adapter, it could be the items or something inside the adapter. so first check your items before creating your adapter. also look my edit and add your adapter code.

Comment: NullPointerException on listView.setAdapter(adapter); I can not imagine what is. :/

Comment: so it must be your listview.  do you init your listview correctly?maby you dont use your custom view as it should be? add your xml layout code pls.

Comment: I'm using a lib LoadMoreListView and ActionCompat Pull to Refresh.
XML: [http://pastebin.com/j8Sv41L8](http://pastebin.com/j8Sv41L8)

Comment: Well, im almost sure your problem is there.Make sure your lib is selected in java build path ->> order and export and clean your project, also why do you set visiblity gone in your layout?

Comment: I'm using this lib [https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore). This is working perfectly, I'm only using LoadMore, for the pullToRefresh I am using ActionBarPullToRefresh. The problem can be in listview...

I set visibility for loading screen, it isn't the complete xml.

Comment: For some reason your listview is null, because if you added all my code we did check if everything is not null before setting the listview. Maby you are doing something wrong.. do step by step debugging until you find where listview is failed to init

Comment: It is as follows:
There are several buttons on the navigation drawer that 
Você quis dizer: funciona
work as filters for categories, when I click this button, it goes to BaseActivity through an interface and passes this information to the FeedFragment, this Fragment calls the method that makes a query (with filter) in database and inserts the data to the list. By the way, the query is working perfectly.

Comment: the query is not our problem, something mess up with your listview, kinda hard helping you with this because im not familiar with the custom listview you are using, like i said, you can try debugging your code once you switch query and look for some errors ...

Comment: I've debugged the code, here the first breakdown: [First](http://imgur.com/zkJHCCP.png) and the second breakdown: [Second](http://i.imgur.com/Ni2EG2Y.png)

Comment: Listview is null, how? I'm instancing it in onCreateView, how could this happen?

Comment: Its working now, but in a very strange way... If someone wants to help me, I can send the project repository.

Comment: if its working now you can accept the answer :) also open a new post for a new problem and i will try helping you there